# How can I run a command in PowerShell with admin rights in the current shell?

Tags: windows, powershell, admin

I attempted to write a short runas-admin function where I could pass another function name as a parameter and have that command executed with admin rights (more or less the equivalent of sudo in linux). When I try running the function it runs continuously and never ends, taking up a lot of cpu. I'm new to PowerShell, so is there something wrong with my code?

```
function runas-admin
{
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
   # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
   $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
   $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
   clear-host
}
else
{
   # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator

   # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
   $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
   $newProcess.RedirectStandardError = $TRUE;
   $newProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = $TRUE;
   $newProcess.UseShellExecute = $FALSE;
   # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
   $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;

   # Indicate that the process should be elevated
   $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

   # Start the new process
   $childProcess = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
   $childProcess.WaitForExit();
   Write-Output $childProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just run `Start-Process` with the verb `runas` e.g.:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runas
```

Comment: To My Knowledge That Would Open a New Shell. I Would Like To Run The Command In The Current Shell (i.e. Window)

Comment: You can use -NoNewWindow to run the new PowerShell process within the current shell.

Comment: I get the following error if I try using a function like get-location `Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.` and I get this error when I try to use the -NoNewWindow switch `Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

Comment: Is there something that you see wrong in the runas-admin function I created? I'd like to be able to get the output of whatever function/script I run and have it displayed to the current shell.